# Redirect dead URLs to new URL in web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I have a few (4) links that need to be redirected in a .net website.  For example, I need http://www.example.com/products/productname (which now longer exists) to redirect to http://www.example.com/products/productname.aspx.

How can I set up 301 redirects in the web.config?

Thanks!

Currently I have the following:

```
<location path="draft_root_beer">
<system.webServer>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="~/products/draft_root_beer.aspx"     httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only adding ".aspx", I suggest you to use [URL Rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx), links will be better for SEO. Otherwise yous something like bellow:

```
<location path="productname">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/products/productname.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: I have the following:
  <location path="draft_root_beer">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="~/products/draft_root_beer.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

but still get a 404 error.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you try it with "ht tp://www.example.com/products..." instead of "~/products..."?

Comment: Look at this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Do I need to somehow enable HTTP redirects in visual studio when I debug?

Comment: @criticalfix yes, same result

Comment: Do you use WebDeV server or IIS?

Comment: Right now i'm just debugging in Visual Studio... so not iis?